# Combinar 2 Arrays por Indice Laravel - PHP

Tags: php, laravel

En esta ocasión deseo unir 2 arrays que tengo generadas con el Framework Laravel:

Este es mi código con el que genero los arrays

```
@foreach($ezpos_product_sale_data as $product_sale_data)

        @php

        $productIds = $ezpos_product_sale_data->pluck('product_id');
        $ezpos_product_data = \App\Product::whereIn('id', $productIds)->select('name as descripcion', 'type as unidad_de_medida', 'code as codigo')->get()->toArray(); 
        $slid = $product_sale_data->sale_id; 
        $lproductos = $product_sale_data::where('sale_id', '=', $slid)->select('net_unit_price as precio')->get()->toArray(); 

        @endphp 


    @endforeach
```

Se generan estos arrays

```
 array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["precio"]=>
    float(800)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["precio"]=>
    float(1000)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["precio"]=>
    float(1200)
  }
}


array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["descripcion"]=>
    string(8) "IPhone X"
    ["unidad_de_medida"]=>
    string(8) "standard"
    ["codigo"]=>
    string(8) "07739340"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["descripcion"]=>
    string(12) "Spectre x360"
    ["unidad_de_medida"]=>
    string(8) "standard"
    ["codigo"]=>
    string(8) "52932406"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["descripcion"]=>
    string(11) "Mac AirBook"
    ["unidad_de_medida"]=>
    string(8) "standard"
    ["codigo"]=>
    string(8) "34807601"
  }
}
```

Lo que quisiera es poder que el array [0] quede con el otro [0], [1] con [1] y así respectivamente combinando el array(1) y array(3) en uno solo.

Espero haberme expresado bien y que esto sea posible de alguna forma.

Comment: ¿Las dos tablas tienen algún campo en común?

Comment: El campo sales_id

Comment: ¿La relación entre las tablas como es (uno a uno), (uno a muchos)?

Comment: lo que yo veo es que las relaciones en las tablas son de uno a uno y de uno a muchos, eso se puede soluciona en el siguiente forma con el uso de hasmany y belongsto, si puede publicar como tiene el modelo le puedo ayuda   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijGHzXu_RkU&t=29s

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar antes de llevar a toArray() las collection usar este código de ejemplo que te propongo.

```
    $merg = collect([0 => ['b' => 2]]);

    $mergOther = collect([0 => ['a' => 4]]);

    collect($mergOther)->map(function ($item, $key) use ($merg) {

        $valueToMerge = $merg[$key];

        $keyMerge = Arr::first(array_keys($valueToMerge));

        $item = Arr::add($item, $keyMerge, Arr::get($valueToMerge, $keyMerge));
        return $item;
    });
```

La idea es usar el método map de las collections de laravel. Espero te sirva de ayuda.

```
@foreach($ezpos_product_sale_data as $product_sale_data)

    @php

      $productIds = $ezpos_product_sale_data->pluck('product_id');
      $ezpos_product_data = \App\Product::whereIn('id', $productIds)->select('name as descripcion', 'type as unidad_de_medida', 'code as codigo')->get(); 
      $slid = $product_sale_data->sale_id; 

      $lproductos = $product_sale_data::where('sale_id', '=', $slid)->select('net_unit_price as precio')->get()->map(function ($item, $key) use ($ezpos_product_data ) {        
          $valueToMerge = $ezpos_product_data[$key];

          $keyMerge = array_first(array_keys((array)$valueToMerge));

          $item = array_add((array)$item, $keyMerge, array_get((array)$valueToMerge, $keyMerge));

         return $item;
      })->toArray(); 


    @endphp 




@endforeach
```

Prueba y me dices. Saludos

Nueva modificación usando el cast a (array)

Comment: Me gustaría poder probar esto, pero no sé como llevar este código al que tengo yo propuesto

Comment: Edité la respuesta incluyéndole el código nuevo a tu código. Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Por alguna razón me genera este error  local.ERROR: Class 'Arr' not found

Comment: si, tranquilo es que necesitas incluir la clase Arr en tu fichero y tener laravel 5.8. En cambio puede usar array_first(), array_add(), array_keys(), array_get()

Comment: Ya hice las modificaciones con array_first(), array_add(), array_keys(), array_get(). Test now

Comment: Muchas Gracias crack, lo copie tal cual pero me genera este error  array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: Nueva modificación usando el cast a (array).

Answer (score 0):

Puede recurrir a un simple `foreach` e ir combinando los elementos, iterar el primer array de datos, y en cada iteración, creamos un nuevo array con los datos que están en la posición *($key)* de ambos arrays.

```
$result = array();
foreach($arrayOne as $key=>$val){ 
    $val2 = $arrayTwo[$key]; 
    $result[$key] = $val + $val2;
}
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://rextester.com/KZX77852)</kbd>